# Can seo be done in signalR Based application in .net or mvc4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, seo, signalr

Can **seo** be done in **signalR** Based application in .net or mvc4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SEO is doing for the page, not for the server side code. You can use the same techniques you use for a usual web application for the web applications using SignalR. SignalR is not related to SEO techniques. SignalR is a library which you can use to integrate real time web functionality to your web application. SEO is mainly based on the content you have on the page.